# Failing to run ng build for prod with ngrx effects

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 5. The app runs with `ng build` and `ng serve`. However it fails with --prod flag for both. Following is the error:

ERROR in Error: Invalid provider for the NgModule 'ɵd in /Users/me/project/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/effects.d.ts' - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [?null?]

Can someone give some hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ridiculous. This problem is because ng-cli doesn't work well with default import in ES6.

In my component.module.ts, I included component.effects.ts as below.

```
import {EffectsModule} from '@ngrx/effects';
import MyEffects from '@app/component/state/component.effects';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        EffectsModule.forFeature([ MyEffects ])
    ],
    ...
})

export class QueryModule {}
```

The error is `import MyEffects from`. I changed it to `import {MyEffects} from` and in my component.effects.ts, I replaced default import with named import.

Comment: I get  a fail build if I do this way.. Why did you put @app?

Comment: @app is a way of angular to shorten the imports. you have to specify it in tsconfig.json in the root dir. https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/shorten-typescript-imports-in-an-angular-project/